# More elegant way to update index into circular list?

Tags: c#

I have a list of questions that the user will iterate through, they can start at any question, but they do have a order to them, so in order to do this I just maintain an index into the array and increment it like so:

```
CurrentQuestion = (++CurrentQuestion < questions.Length) ? CurrentQuestion : 0;
```

It isn't necessarily obvious what is happening here, is there a more elegant way to do this?

Comment: Sure, abstract that behavior into a method somewhere with a nice clear name.

Comment: Note that your chosen answer is still as non-maintainable as this answer, and just as elegant, but with a different semantic.

Comment: @jcolebrand - at least the answer got rid of the `++`, and Lou is right about it being the idiomatic way.

Comment: @jcolebrand I am not sure that I agree with you as far as maintainability goes...the chosen answer is one line of code, and is clear as day as to what it does. I don't see how changing one line of concise code to 4 lines of code and 2 lines of comments makes the code more maintainable. In certain circumstances yes, but this line is very clear, and it can be maintained just as easily.

Comment: Oh I'm not disagreeing with that, I was rather pointing out to future readers to come across this question. For your benefit I was pointing out this was _as elegant_ as your existing answer. Note I did both upvote and positively comment on the solution.

Comment: `++` in the middle of a non-trivial expression is a red-flag to a lot of programmers.  You need to understand exactly when the `++` will be applied, which makes the line harder to read, and it might be wrong.  There are no such problems with my answer, so I would say that it's better in that respect.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I have a strong aversion to using `++` on a variable and then that variable again in the same statement.  I believe this line works fine in C#, but lines like this are undefined in C/C++, and so they raise a flag for me.  I would prefer

```
CurrentQuestion = (CurrentQuestion+1) % questions.Length;
```

Which I think of as the idiomatic way of doing clock-arithmetic in C-like languages.

Comment: Oh, that's a good option too, I didn't even consider the modulo, but you're right.

Comment: you have to test if 'question.Length' is greater than zero, else, you will get an exception.

Comment: Another Problem: If the value of CurrentQuestion gets greater than int.MaxValue CurrentQuestion will continue at int.MinValue. This means you'll get negative values from Modulo. Either you use [Math.Abs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.math.abs(v=vs.110).aspx) or uint (then it starts from 0 when it reaches uint.MaxValue).

Answer (score 3):

> It isn't necessarily obvious what is happening here, is there a more elegant way to do this?

While it's not immediately obvious to some, I know exactly what that's doing.

However, what you may want to consider is that it's more important to write readable code than it is to be clever. Code has to be maintained, and you are NOT smarter than the compiler.

Write the code like thus, and be happy with it:

```
//ensure that the CurrentQuestion counter increments and loops back around after hitting "list max"
CurrentQuestion = CurrentQuestion + 1;
if (CurrentQuestion >= questions.Length) {
  CurrentQuestion = 0;
} // meta-comment: use braces incase you have to add more later
```

The important bit is that this code is now readable, and it's still optimized. It does *exactly* what the other code does, and we can change parts later without a lot of re-reading of the code.

Also note some semantics I used here.

- Always use the braces, even when you don't think you need them.
- Do `CurrentQuestion = CurrentQuestion + 1;` instead of either `CurrentQuestion += 1;` or `CurrentQuestion++;` or `++CurrentQuestion;` because the first is much more explicit on intent. Always write intentful code.

Comment: Check again - I think your current version allows `CurrentQuestion` to equal `questions.Length`

Comment: Whoops, you're right, I flipped but forgot to add the =, thanks. This is why collaborative review is great :D

Comment: I feel like using ++ or += is explicit enough on intent, are you saying you never use them in code? That seems to be going slightly overboard.

Comment: While the gist of this answer is clear, the logic in the sample code (as of right this moment... jcolebrand seems to still be editing it) is incorrect.  The increment operation (`CurrentQuestion = CurrentQuestion + 1`) should be done before the loop-around check, assuming that `CurrentQuestion` is a zero-based index.

Comment: I don't just because they have the same effect here. I'm not saying never use them, because I use them when I'm incrementing a loop counter. I just don't use them when I'm doing assignments like this because someone may want to add something else in midstream as well. It just presents better in some ways.

Comment: @csd you're right, I failed to take that into account. In that case, we would remove the else, and place the assignment above. Let me do that now.

Comment: @NominSim additionally, it's not that it's _clearer_ to write `CurrentQuestion += 1;` in this case, it's that it's more _maintainable_. I keep conflating my point I see. >.<

Answer (score 1):

There's no need for the conditional operator

```
 CurrentQuestion = ++CurrentQuestion % questions.Length;
```

but I guess which one you prefer is a matter of style more than anything else

Comment: This technically breaks for large iterations though.

Comment: @NominSim only if it's going to wrap. However since that would require  more elements in the array than can actually be fitted in that's not really a concern. (to be more precise with exactly the maximum number of elements this would break)

Comment: @KirkWoll Yeah sorry that's what I meant.

Comment: Though a compiler would probably optimize it away, this answer is possibly slower than Lou Franco's answer since it involves two assignments to `CurrentQuestion`: the one from the increment (`++CurrentQuestion`) and the one from the equals.

Comment: Ouch. `++` on the target of the assignment?

Comment: @csd if we are for speed the conditional operator is faster than this I personally think this is easier on the eye than `CurrentQuestion+1` and it's probably not going to be any slower since it's will be rather simple to optimize away